# Java - constructing objects from different, separate classes and adding them to the sameArray List

Tags: java, object, parameters, constructor

I'm trying to make a method that constructs a new instance of an object and adds it to an array list. The catch is that there are a couple different classes/objects that can be used and all new instances have to be created by the same method, so I have to be able to pass in to the method the type of object I wish to create, as well as the constructor's parameters (the parameters are always the same, three int's and a String).

```
public void makeAppointment(Object app, int a, int b, int c, String desc){
    app.getClass();
}
```

This is my best guess on what to do for the method that takes in all the information. Is there a way to store what `app.getClass();` returns so that I can use it to call a constructor?

I already have a method (addAppointment) that adds an object to the ArrayList that I can call from this method that I am working on.

```
public static List<Appointment> apps = new ArrayList<Appointment>();

public AppointmentBook addAppointment(Appointment app) {
    apps.add(app);
    return this;
}
```

------- EDIT

So here is the full class:

```
public class AppointmentBook {

public static List<Appointment> apps = new ArrayList<Appointment>();

public AppointmentBook addAppointment(Appointment app) {
    apps.add(app);
    return this;
}

public void addAppointment(int month, int day, int year, String desc) {
    Appointment appointment = new Appointment(month, day, year, desc);
    apps.add(appointment);
}// addApp

public void addOnetime(int month, int day, int year, String desc) {
    Onetime oneTime = new Onetime(month, day, year, desc);
    apps.add(oneTime);
}// addOnce

public void addMonthly(int month, int day, int year, String desc) {
    Monthly monthly = new Monthly(month, day, year, desc);
    apps.add(monthly);
}// addMonth

public void addDaily(int month, int day, int year, String desc) {
    Daily daily = new Daily(month, day, year, desc);
    apps.add(daily);
}// addMonth

public void makeAppointment(Object app, int a, int b, int c, String desc){
    Class<? extends Object> a = app.getClass();

}
```

}// class

I have the class Appointment book which has an array list that stores appointments. I have the class Appointment with three subclasses. Each of these subclasses has a constructor that constructs an object. I want use the method `makeAppointment` to add an appointment, but I don't know how to specify which kind of object I would like to create in parameters so that I can call the constructor inside the method.

Comment: OK, so what's your question?

Comment: is there a way to store what `app.getClass();` returns so that I can use it to call a constructor?

Comment: Give us more information: What kind of 'different classes' do you have? I assume they are all subclasses of `Appointment`, aren't they? And how/where do you decide which class to instantiate?

Comment: Yes there are three subclasses of `Appointment` and which class is initiated is decided in the parameters, or at least that's what I'm thinking would be the right way to go about this

Answer (score 0):

To me it is not really clear what you are trying to achieve.
But my best guess is polymorphism.

You need a class which will define your list

```
public class AppointmentList extends ArrayList{
}
```

from your main class you can initialize the appointmentlist to hold Appointments

And all the Appointments you want to add need to extend the abstract class Appointment. If you pass your main class to all the classes that need it you can call the add appointment method from there.

I hope i did understand your problem and solved it. Else you need to give me some more of your code